# How to detect if all the rows of a non-square matrix are orthogonal in python

Tags: python, math, numpy, scipy

I can test the rank of a matrix using np.linalg.matrix_rank(A) . But how can I test if all the rows of A are orthogonal efficiently?

I could take all pairs of rows and compute the inner product between them but is there a better way?

My matrix has fewer rows than columns and the rows are not unit vectors.

Comment: I think this is called semi-orthogonal but I don't know if there is code for it.

Comment: One of the definitions of an orthogonal matrix is that `A.dot(A.T)` will be the identity matrix.  That should give a fairly efficient test, and it's easy to measure how "close to orthogonal" it is by comparing the RMS difference of `A.dot(A.T)` and `np.eye(A.shape)`. Don't have time for a complete answer right now, but hopefully the suggestion is useful (and hopefully someone else will give a more complete answer).

Comment: @JoeKington Isn't that only for orthonormal matrices? My rows are not unit vectors.

Comment: @eleanora - Ah, right.  You're quite correct.  I think the off diagonal terms should (?) still be zero, though, even if the rows aren't unit vectors.  I could be completely off base there, though. However, if it's not square, all of that is out of the window (missed the non-square part on the first read-through).

Comment: @JoeKington, you're correct: if the rows are orthogonal, the off-diagonal terms of `A.dot(A.T)` will be 0.  (This is assuming the values in `A` are all real.  If they are complex, then `A.dot(A.T.conj())` will be a diagonal matrix.)  And it is true for a nonsquare matrix.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that this will do

```
product = np.dot(A,A.T)
np.fill_diagonal(product,0)
if (product.any() == 0):
```

Comment: Your last line seems off. Do you mean `if (product != 0).any(): raise Exception("not orthogonal")`? I wouldn't check for exact equality, either, rather something like `if (np.abs(product) > tol).any(): raise ...`

Answer (score 6):

*This answer basically summarizes the approaches mentioned in the question and the comments, and adds some comparison/insights about them*

---

**Approach #1 -- checking all row-pairs**

As you suggested, you can iterate over all row pairs, and compute the inner product. If `A.shape==(N,M)`, i.e. you have N rows of size M each, you end up with a O(M*N^2) complexity.

**Approach #2 -- matrix multiplication**

As suggested in the comments by @JoeKington, you can compute the multiplication `A.dot(A.T)`, and check all the non-diagonal elements. Depending on the algorithm used for matrix multiplication, this can be [faster](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication#Algorithms_for_efficient_matrix_multiplication) than the naive O(M*N^2) algorithm, but only asymptotically better. Unless your matrices are big, they would be slower.

---

The advantages of approach #1:

- You can "short circuit" -- quit the check as soon as you find the first non-orthogonal pair
- requires less memory. In #2, you create a temporary NxN matrix.

The advantages of approach #2:

- The multiplication is fast, as it is implemented in the heavily-optimized linear-algebra library (BLAS of ATLAS). I believe those libraries choose the right algorithm to use according to input size (i.e. they won't use the fancy algorithms on small matrices, because they are slower for small matrices. There's a big constant hidden behind that O-notation).
- less code to write

My bet is that for small matrices, approach #2 would prove faster due to the fact the LA libraries are heavily optimized, and despite the fact they compute the entire multiplication, even after processing the first pair of non-orthogonal rows.

Comment: @JoeKington I believe it applies to non-square matrices.

Comment: There is a third approach, compute the QR decomposition of A^T. If the rows are orthogonal, the R factor will be diagonal. It might be a little bit more numerically stable than computing A*A^T, the computational effort is essentially the same.

Comment: @LutzL interesting. Why won't you add an answer describing it in more details?

Answer (score 3):

## Approach #3: Compute the QR decomposition of A<sup>T</sup>

In general, to find an orthogonal basis of the range space of some matrix X, one can compute the QR decomposition of this matrix (using Givens rotations or Householder reflectors). Q is an orthogonal matrix and R upper triangular. The columns of Q corresponding to non-zero diagonal entries of R form an orthonormal basis of the range space.

If the columns of X=A<sup>T</sup>, i.e., the rows of A, already are orthogonal, then the QR decomposition will necessarily have the R factor diagonal, where the diagonal entries are plus or minus the lengths of the columns of X resp. the rows of A.

Common folklore has it that this approach is numerically better behaved than the computation of the product A*A<sup>T</sup>=R<sup>T</sup>*R. This may only matter for larger matrices. The computation is not as straightforward as the matrix product, however, the amount of operations is of the same size.

Answer (score 1):

```
(U.T @ U == np.eye(U.shape[0])).all()
```

This will give 'True' if matrix 'U' is orthogonal otherwise 'False', here 'all()' function is used to convert the matrix of boolean values(True/False values) that we get after 'U.T @ U == np.eye(U.shape[0])', into a single boolean value.

if you want to check that matrix is approximately orthonormal(by this I mean that the matrix that we get after 'U.T @ U' is nearly equal to an identity matrix),
Then use 'np.allclose()' like this

```
np.allclose(U.T @ U, np.eye(U.shape[0]))
```

Note: '@' is used for matrix multiplication